# What is the best way to hand action sheet action with UITableview Longpress on Ipad

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview that present an alert when long pressed. It work fine on the iphone but on ipad I get the popover error. The problem is that the table is not a button and i have no button on the cell what is the best way to work around this? Please take a look at my code.

```
 func ipadPresentationAlert(button:UIButton, alertController:UIAlertController){
        if ( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad ){
            if let currentPopoverpresentioncontroller = alertController.popoverPresentationController{
                currentPopoverpresentioncontroller.sourceView = button
                currentPopoverpresentioncontroller.sourceRect = button.bounds;
                currentPopoverpresentioncontroller.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.up;
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }else{
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your error log?

Comment: What's the button in your code then?

Comment: if you don't have a button, why is in there a button variable? I think you just need to fill sourceRect

Comment: You can replace your `button` by `yourCell`. `button:UIButton` -> `cell: UITableViewCell`.

Comment: @carlos21 that is a func that i use whenever i have a button visible.

Comment: Why do you have different code for different devices? Just use the same code as the iPad code for all devices. iOS will do the right thing.

Comment: @rmaddy not when you are using actionSheet as the alert

Comment: @Khuong your answer did work using the cell as a button. can you add that as the answer so I can provide you with the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your button by yourCell.

`button:UIButton -> cell: UITableViewCell`

On iPad, `ActionSheet` need a sourceView to be showed, so you can place your cell here as a fulcrum.

```
currentPopoverpresentioncontroller.sourceView = cell
```