# How to trigger an action sheet alert on UITableview cell press on iPadOS

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiactionsheet

I have some code to bring up an action sheet when a cell in a UITableView is pressed. It works fine on the phone but on the iPad it fails. I have see other people with this problem, needing to reconfigure their action sheet alert code somehow, but all I've seen is for triggering an action sheet on a button press. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43083339/what-is-the-best-way-to-hand-action-sheet-action-with-uitableview-longpress-on-i) post, but I could not figure out how to implement this provided sample code:

```
currentPopoverpresentioncontroller.sourceView = cell
```

Here is my function to show the action sheet:

```
    func showActionSheet() {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Card Actions", message: "choose action", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default, handler: { action in
            print("edit tapped")
            self.renameDeckAlert()
    }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
            self.showDeleteAlert()
    }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
    }))
        present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

And here is where I call the function:

```
extension EditViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You tapped cell #\(indexPath.row)")
        showActionSheet()
        self.editTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Can somebody tell me how to bring up an action sheet on iPadOS when a cell in a tableview is pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in the `indexPath` of the selected cell to your presenting function. Then, get the cell with [`cellForRow(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614983-cellforrow):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    showActionSheet(indexPath: indexPath) /// pass in the indexPath
    self.editTableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

///                  ↓ add an argument label
func showActionSheet(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Card Actions", message: "choose action", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default, handler: { action in
        print("edit tapped")
        
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: { action in
        
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { action in
    }))
    
    /// for iPad
    if let popoverController = alert.popoverPresentationController {
        
        /// get the cell
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        
        popoverController.sourceView = cell
        popoverController.sourceRect = cell?.bounds ?? CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    }
    
    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

Result:

| iPhone | iPad |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Action sheet presented at the bottom of the screen] | [image: Action sheet presented directly underneath the cell, with an arrow pointing to it] |

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thanks!